# Is there an event logged somewhere when a WinRT app exceeds it's background task quota?

Tags: windows-runtime

I have a WinRT application that allows for push notifications.  When a push notification comes in I pull some data out of the message, then do some web service calls to find what files I need to download, create background downloads for each of the files, then log some data for the main application to use when it picks next runs so it knows how to understand the active background downloads.

Most of these actions are done using async/await to minimize CPU time and locally on my development machine everything seems to be working perfectly.  Unfortunately, the client's QA is saying that it's not working, debug logs are showing them getting the push notification but it does not seem to be progressing much past that.

I have a bad feeling that they are probably hitting the CPU quota but unfortunately I can't prove it.

Is there anything logged anywhere to show when the operating system kills (or suspends???) a background process due to exceeding the cpu quota?